# SHA3 CryptoJS equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, cryptojs

I have data encrypted with CryptoJS using SHA3 like [this example](http://jscode.online/examples/CryptoJS_SHA3). I try to write in C# using [SHA3.NET](https://github.com/dariogriffo/sha3.net), a BouncyCastle wrapper.

```
using (var shaAlg = SHA3.Net.Sha3.Sha3512())
{
    var hash = shaAlg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
    var hashString = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

Using the BouncyCastle directly generates the same result as above (not matched CryptoJS).

```
var hashAlgorithm = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha3Digest(512);
byte[] input = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
hashAlgorithm.BlockUpdate(input, 0, input.Length);
byte[] result = new byte[64];
hashAlgorithm.DoFinal(result, 0);
string hashString = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
```

When passing `data` parameter `abc` the result should be `18587dc2ea106b9a1563e32b3312421ca164c7f1f07bc922a9c83d77cea3a1e5d0c69910739025372dc14ac9642629379540c17e2a65b19d77aa511a9d00bb96` but the result is `b751850b1a57168a5693cd924b6b096e08f621827444f70d884f5d0240d2712e10e116e9192af3c91a7ec57647e3934057340b4cf408d5a56592f8274eec53f0`

Comment: Try using Encoding.UTF8 instead of ASCII.  ASCII will remove non printable characters.

Comment: `b7...f0` is correct, as you can easily check, e.g. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=SHA3('512')&input=YWJj). How do you get `18...96?` If CryptoJS returns this result, you should post the code.

Comment: You can find it here: http://jscode.online/examples/CryptoJS_SHA3

Comment: You should post the CryptoJS code in the question and not just the link (in case the link eventually dies). CryptoJS uses Keccak and wrongly calls this SHA3, see the documentation, [Hashing](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hashing), section _SHA-3_.

Comment: It's now solved. Thank you @Topaco